# Stuck at "Retrieving character list"

Tags: azerothcore

In my [AzerothCore](http://www.azerothcore.org/) whenever I try to login, it's stuck at `Retrieving character list`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue is truncating the table `instance_reset` of the characters database (`acore_characters`).

Comment: I thought it was fixed (by nefertumm's PR)... Issue got closed and it comes back again. This is not a solution if you need to truncate each time

Comment: i think you need to truncate it the first time for AzerothCore < 2.0, because that table was filled in default database.
With AC 2.0 it should be ok now. Could you link the nefertumm PR?